# Conditional proability store

Tags: probability

can you help me on this?

Three stores have 8, 12, and 15 employees of whom 3, 8, and 7, respectively, are women. A store is chosen at random and from that store an employee is chosen at random. If this employee is a woman, what is the probability she came from the store with 12 employees?

I did:

Let A be the event the employee chosen is a Woman.

Let B be the event the chosen store is the store with 12 employees.

To find condicional Probability of P(B|A) I used:

P(B|A)=P(AandB)/P(A)

Where:
P(A)=18/35

P(AandB)=2/3

But the result of it is greater than 1.

P(B|A)=(2/3)/(18/35)=1.29 which is wrong.

Do you know what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: P(A and B) should be far less than 2/3, how did you get that?

Comment: P(A) is calculated incorrectedly

Comment: there are 8 women in store with 12 employees so Probability of A and B 8/12=2/3

Comment: For P(A) I did: there are 18 women in 35 all employees (8+12+15)

Comment: @user290335 look at my answer for help

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of the other users to understand the solution to this question, I'll redo the entire problem.

As you stated in your question, you identified that this problem requires Bayes Theorem and conditional probability.

Let $A$ be the event that the chosen employee is a woman, and $B$ be the event that the chosen woman came from the store with $12$ employees.

We are trying to find the probability of $B$ given $A$, or $P(B|A)$:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$

Lets first calculate $P(A \cap B)$, the probability the employee is a woman and came from the store with $12$ employees.

We have a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance of choosing the store with $12$ employees, since they are $3$ stores, and there is a $\frac{8}{12}$ chance to select a woman, since there are $8$ women in the store with $12$ employees.

We then multiply these $2$ probabilities to get:

$$P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{3}*\frac{8}{12} = \frac{2}{9}$$

Now, lets calculate $P(A)$, or the probability that the chosen employee is a woman.

For this probability we look at the $3$ stores, and calculate the probabilities that a woman is chosen from each of these stores.

As stated earlier, the probability that we choose one of the $3$ stores is $\frac{1}{3}$.

For the first store, we have that the probability of choosing a woman is $\frac{3}{8}$.

For the second store, we have that the probability of choosing a woman is $\frac{8}{12}$.

For the third store, we have that the probability of choosing a woman is $\frac{7}{15}$.

Therefore, our total probability is:

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{3}*\frac{3}{8} + \frac{1}{3}*\frac{8}{12} + \frac{1}{3}*\frac{7}{15} = \frac{181}{360}$$

We therefore have our answer:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{\frac{2}{9}}{\frac{181}{360}} = \frac{80}{181}$$

Hope this helped. Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Do I have to assume that Events A and B are independents because P(AandB)=8/12*1/3=2/9

Comment: @user290335 yes you do

Comment: So in this case I understood how to calculate the probability of A and the probabilily of A and B. Thank you for your help